# Apache Kafka w/ Spring Boot - message batch size stuck around 7337

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am testing Kafka installed on an AWS instance where the consumers (Java-based) are consistently getting batches of 7,337 messages but no more.

**What configuration options should I look at in order to see if I can make those batches larger?**  It's set to 25,000 but never actually gets there.  The producers drop in 1,000,000 records pretty much instantly, so it's up to the consumers at this point.

Currently my consumers are set to:

- ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG = false
- ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG = 100
- ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = earliest
- ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG = 15000
- ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG = 25000
- Concurrency: 5
- Poll Timeout Milliseconds:  10,000

The annotation for the consumer is pretty basic.

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer {

  @KafkaListener (id = "datastore-ictx", topics = "datastore-ictx")
  public void receive(List<String> batch) {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: How big are the messages? See `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and `fetch.max.bytes` in the kafka docs.

Comment: That's, I'll look at that, but it's just a string of 128 characters.